# Prove that there are uncountably many surjective functions f : N → N

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can you help me determine what I am doing wrong in this proof? Is this sufficient? [image]

Comment: Please do not include pictures; they cannot be searched.

Comment: Just study functions that permute $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}\cdots $. This will yield uncountably many bijections even.

Comment: Why do you think it might be wrong?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is perfect.

Even more than sufficient, as you state once that $g$ is clearly surjective, as already its restriction to even numbers is so, and then in the end you spell it out again.